# Java sorting program confusion

Tags: java, class, sorting, methods

I have an assignment I'm working on for my java course.  We have to create a program that asks the user to enter several integers and then they make a choice of which type of sorting method they'd like to use (i.e. Selection, Bubble, and Insertion).

Directions state we should have a driver class and a class called Sorter. Class Sorter would have the methods for the different sorting options.

My issue is, I started with insertion sort and got that all up and going and thought the easy part would be separating it into different classes but I'm having a hard time doing that.  I thought I'd use a switch for the "menu" and just add the different methods for the different sorting algorithms in methods below that.  I can't figure out how to get it working properly though.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, does my insertion sort look ok?  I thought it would be better to use an array list rather than a fixed array, that proved to be harder than I thought too.

Here is my code...

Driver class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DriverSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);
    /* System.out.println("1-Insertion sort\n"
                    +"2-Selection sort\n"
                    + "3-Bubble sort\n"
                    + "0-quit\n"
                    + "Please enter the number for a sorting method or enter 0 to quit: ");
    option = scan.nextInt(); */

     //Instantiate and call Insertion sort. 

    String list="";

    ArrayList<Integer> arrlist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Welcome to the sorting application menu, the following sorting" 
            + "methods are available: ");
    System.out.println("Please enter the list of elements: ");
    System.out.println(" write 'STOP' when list is completed ");


    while(!(list=scan.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
        int intelement = Integer.parseInt(list);
        arrlist.add(intelement);           
    }

    int elementlist[]  = new int[arrlist.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iter = arrlist.iterator();
    for (int j=0;iter.hasNext();j++) {
        elementlist[j] = iter.next();
    }

    elementlist = Sorter.insertionSort(elementlist);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Values after Insertion Sort : ");
    for (int j=0;j<elementlist.length;j++) {
        System.out.print(elementlist[j]+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Sorter class

```
public class Sorter {

public int getMenu() {
    int option = 0;

    switch (option) {

    case 0:
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
        break;

    case 1: //Insertion Sort    

        //method for insertion algorithm
        public static int[] insertionSort(int[] list) {
            for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
                int next = list[i];
                // find the insertion location while moving all larger elements up
                int j = i;
                while (j > 0 && list[j - 1] > next) {
                    list[j] = list[j - 1];
                    j--;
                }//end while

                // insert the element
                list[j] = next;
            }//end for loop
            return list;
        }//end insertionSort



    }//end switch
  } 
}
```

Comment: You can't define a method in a switch.

Comment: Yeah I should've clarified that...That's unfinished code.  I wasn't sure what to add to the switch to work with the insertionSort method that would then work with the driver class.  I just got lost.

Comment: The menu should not be in the `Sorter` class. The Sorter has one responsibility which is to sort (implemented in different ways, but still). The menu should be part of the Driver class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you are more confused about the design rather than about the code. Anyways, you can easily find the [sorting implementations on the web](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/04Sorting.pdf), so I'll just try to help you out the design.

```
public class DriverSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        private static Sorter sorter = new Sorter();

        // blah blah blah
        // take the input in an array or alist

        int choice;  // variable which says which sorting algorithm to use
        int[] arr;   // list of inputs to be sorted

        switch (choice) 
        {
            case 0: sorter.InsertionSort(are);
                    sorter.print(arr);
                    break;

            case 1: sorter.QuickSort(arr);
                    sorter.print(arr);
                    break;

            // and so on…

            default:
                    break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep the `Driver` class independent of any sorting and printing logic. Handle that piece of code in the `Sorter` class.

```
public class Sorter {

    public int[] InsertionSort(int[] arr)
    {
        // implement specific sorting logic
        return arr;
    }

    public int[] SelectionSort(int[] arr)
    {
        // implement specific sorting logic
        return arr;
    }

    public int[] QuickSort(int[] arr)
    {
        // implement specific sorting logic
        return arr;
    }

    public int[] ShellSort(int[] arr)
    {
        // implement specific sorting logic
        return arr;
    }

    public void print(int[] arr)
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes confused by the design.  I get royal confused with methods, classes and parameters.  I understand your code though, thanks a lot!  One question, you said use either array or arraylist, is there a better choice?

Comment: Use `Arrays` in this case, because `ArrayList` is internally implemented using `Arrays'.

Comment: Quick, change the method names according to the usual form. Novices shouldn't have to unlearn.

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

The description isn't quite clear, but this is one way of doing it:

What should be written is an abstract class (or interface) Sorter with a single abstract method 'void sort( int[] list )`. Then you write three classes extending (or implementing) Sorter, one for of the sorting methods; here method sort actually implements the algorithm.

The "driver" does the dialogue, creates a Sorter subclass instance and calls sort.

```
public abstract class Sorter {
     public abstract void sort( int[] list );
}

public class InsertionSorter extends Sorter {
    public void sort( int[] list ){
         // implement insertion sort
    }
}

public class Driver {
    public void sortUsing(){
         int iSort = ...;
         int[] list = ...; 
         Sorter sorter = null;
         switch( iSort ){
         case 1:
             sorter = new InsertionSorter();
             break;
         // cases 2, 3,...
         default:
             throw ...;
         }
         sorter.sort( list );
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks Laune!  What is abstract?  And also int iSort = ...;  What's the ... again?  Sorry I'm super new.

Comment: "abstract" indicates that a method is "promised to be implemented by non-abstract subclasses". An abstract class (typically) contains one or more abstract methods.